# Delta Lake Table shows data in Glue but not in Athena

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am writing data to S3 in delta format from Spark dataframe in Glue. When I read the same table back in a dataframe, I am able to see the data. I created a table in Athena pointing to this S3 location (using the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command and not Glue crawler). When I query the data in Athena, I get zero records. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you pointed the location properly in DDL. You can try running `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>`

Comment: Did you generate the manifest file? https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-utility.html#generate-a-manifest-file

Comment: @MohanaBC : yes location was properly pointed to. I tried running MSCK REPAIR TABLE  however Athena didn't allow.

My Athena engine version was 2.0 while delta tables are only supported starting 3.0. Upgrading resolved the issue.

Comment: @meysam: With the latest version, you don't need to generate MANIFEST file

My Athena engine version was 2.0 while delta tables are only supported starting 3.0. Upgrading resolved the issue.